# Highlighting word by word using jquery

Tags: jquery

How to highlight the text in div at particular time interval. The time interval has been mentioned in "intervals" attribute of the each div. Is it possible to change interval the time as dynamically in setInterval or setTimeout function. I have written the structure of the HTML and jquery code that I am using.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  .green_class{
   background-color:green;
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#btnclick").click(function(){
        var childs=$("#test").children();
        $(childs).each(function(){
         var time_interval=$(this).attr("intervals");
         setTimeout(function(){$(this).addClass("green_class");},parseInt(time_interval));
        });
     });
   });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test" style="float:left">
        <div intervals="0">Lorem&nbsp;</div>
        <div intervals="500">Ipsum&nbsp;</div>
        <div intervals="800">is&nbsp;</div>
        <div intervals="1000">simply&nbsp;</div>
        <div intervals="1200">dummy&nbsp;</div>
        <div intervals="1400">text&nbsp;</div>
        <div intervals="1600">of&nbsp;</div>
        <div intervals="1800">the&nbsp;</div>
        <div intervals="2000">printing&nbsp;</div>
        <div intervals="2200">and&nbsp;</div>
        <div intervals="2400">typesetting&nbsp;</div>
        <div intervals="2600">industry</div>
    </div>
<input type="button" value="Highlight" id="btnclick"/>
</body>
</html>
```

The above script is not working properly. Is it possible to change the setTimeout function time duration dynamically. Please give your valuable suggestions/solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Your expando property "intervals" should be referenced as `attr("intervals")`, not `attr(intervals)`

Additionally, I think you can do `childs.each` rather than `$(childs).each`, as `childs` is already a jQueryified object.

Answer (score 1):

Imporved code http://jsfiddle.net/NyuWb/ 
You also invoke `$(this).addClass("green_class");` in wrong context.
So my version:

```
$("#btnclick").click(function() {
    $("#test").children().each(function() {
        var time_interval = $(this).attr('intervals'),
            _this = $(this);

        setTimeout(function() {
            _this.addClass("green_class");
        }, parseInt(time_interval));
    });
});
```

Comment: It takes time interval only once. Please kindly check... The time duration is distributed uniformly. There is no change.. Simply I mean that the time interval not changed dynamically. For an example I have extended upto 2600 ms. But you can identify that the highlighting is in uniform speed. Please kindly check with that...

Comment: You specify intervals as 800, 1000, 1200, etc with the 200ms increment. So sure highlighting is in uniform speed.

Comment: Hi, Actually the text should highlight its exact interval, which is in "intervals" attribute. Not the differences btw two intervals. What I mean is if the intervals is 800, it should highlight after the 800 ms. If the interval is 1500ms, it should highlight after 1500ms only. Is it possible...?